# Echo content between tags?

Tags: php

Is it possible to get and then echo the content in between tags using only `PHP`?

For instance. If this is the following `HTML`:

```
<td class="header subject">Text</td>
```

How can you get `Text` from inside the tags and then `echo` it?

I thought this would work:

```
<? 
preg_match("'<td class=\"header subject\">(.*?)</td>'si", $source, $match);
if($match) echo "result=".$match[1];
?>
```

But the `$source` variable has to be the entire page.

Note: There is only one instance of the `header subject` class, so there shouldn't be a problem with multiple tags.

Comment: Your code *does* work - what's the problem?

Comment: regexes on html are ALWAYS going to be unreliable. HTML is not a regular language. Use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your problem is because you don't know how to interpret the page, you might want to try this:

```
<?php 
$lines = file("/path/to/file.html");
foreach($lines as $i => $line)
{
   if (preg_match("'<td class=\"header subject\">(.*?)</td>'si", $line, $match))
   {
      echo "result=". $match[$i];
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should parse the text using the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class, and grab the `textContent` of the element.

```
$html = '<td class="header subject">Text</td>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $html );

// Text
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName("td")->item(0)->textContent;
```

Or if you need to cycle through many `td` elements and only show the text of those that have the class value `"header subject"`, you could do the following:

```
$tds = $dom->getElementsByTagName("td");

for ( $i = 0; $i < $tds->length; $i++ ) {
  $currentTD = $tds->item($i);
  $classAttr = $currentTD->attributes->getNamedItem("class");
  if ( $classAttr && $classAttr->nodeValue === "header subject" ) {
    echo $currentTD->textContent;
  }
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/o1xqrnRS